# JMeter Response data submit to continue for next actions

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, beanshell

I came across some problem in Jmeetere if you guys have some advice please shave with me.  I send request for my application, and i click after the link open, in Response data i got **Script is disabled. Please click Submit to continue**
**Submit** . the submit in response data is a click button, if i click it, it takes to the application site. I tried BeanShell PreProcessor, but still couldn`t  solve it.

Thanks

Comment: JMeter doesn't work on UI level, so not sure what are you talking about:  recording? running selenium-based JMeter test? Can you please provide more information, as well as formulate your question better, as it's hard to read at the moment.

Comment: very badly formatter question,, please add more details before putting up qiestions

Comment: sorry about the confusion. It is a HTTP request sampler, not recordings. I sent HTTP request, i got responses. I added listener, view result tree, i changed  text  response to HTML, then i see the click button in the sampler result Response Data, so I am not sure if the response data is clickable or not .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View Result Tree with HTML view is very limited, as [JMeter Reference specifies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree):

> The HTML view attempts to render the response as HTML. The rendered HTML is likely to compare poorly to the view one would get in any web browser; however, it does provide a quick approximation that is helpful for initial result evaluation.
>   Images, style-sheets, etc. aren't downloaded.

This view will not run any JS scripts either. In your case for instance, it looks like the page returned as a result of the HTTP request depends on JavaScript, and thus developers of that page added a  tag, which is displayed if you try to load the page where JavaScript is not present. If you look at *Text* view of the page, you will see the entiere returned page, and it will contain something like:

```
....
<noscript>Script is disabled. Please click Submit to continue<button value="Submit" type="submit"/></noscript>
...
```

When you switch to *HTML View*, it will only display that section, since JavaScript is not present.

Bottom line: HTML view is very limited, and does not support your page. Use *Text* view instead to understand what your script returns.

Comment: Thank you very much Kiril. This is exactly what I had in my JMeter request. It helped a lot, really appreciated ! In that case, the submit  can can be clickable in Jmeter or has limitation ? Thanks

Comment: No, it's not going to work, since what you see in View Result Tree is just a recording of the last session.

Comment: got you. Thank you Kirlis appreciated !